# Force Interface/Class to define a string variable in Derived Class?

Tags: c#, class, interface, typechecking

I can illustrate this problem best with an example.

I have an interface that forces developers to implement a specific function. I would also like this interface to force the users to implement a set or get property that sets the name of the derived class in a string stored within the class. So if a developer creates a new class that derives from this interface they are forced to:

> 1. Create a definition for the the method.
> 2. Store the name of the derived class in a string called "derivedType"

I would like to store the name as a string in the derived type because I would like to do some type checking at runtime on objects that implement this interface.

```
public interface someInterface
{
   int someMethod(int x);
   string derivedType {get; set;}
}

public derivedClass : someInterface
{
   public int someMethod (int x) {...};
   public string derivedType
   {
      get {return this.derivedType;}
      set {derivedType = "derivedClass";}
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you create a property with a setter but then ignore the value which it tried to set? And why are you setting the value to `derivedType` rather than `derivedClass`?

Comment: Oh, and note that declaring a *property* is not the same thing as declaring a *variable*.

Comment: @JonSkeet He also omitted the `class` keyword from `derivedClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things - first, your example implementation is not correct.  It will raise a `StackOverflowException` if you try to get `derivedType` (since it's returning itself).  In general, a setter would not be required here:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
   int SomeMethod(int x);
   string DerivedType {get;}
}

public class DerivedClass : ISomeInterface
{
   public int DomeMethod (int x) {...};
   public string DerivedType
   {
      get {return "derivedType"; }
   }
}
```

That being said, there is no way to *force* the implementer to do this correctly.  If you want to guarantee that the name will be correct, you could just use reflection instead of putting this into the interface (`object.GetType().Name`).

Comment: So then I don't even need the string if I were to use object.GetType().Name in my type checking method ?

Comment: @user1084113 Yeah - Using `GetType().Name` on the instance will return the name of the type via reflection.

Comment: Very nice, didn't know I could do that. Thanks.

Comment: So in the class definition of derivedClass could I also call something like string _myClassName = this.getType().Name()

Comment: @user1084113 You could - though typically you would just call that from where you need it, and leave it out of the interface.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Where is the `class` keyword in `public DerivedClass : ISomeInterface`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) instead.

```
ISomeInterface myObject = new DerivedClass();
Type myType = myObject.GetType();
string typeName = myType.Name; // "DerivedClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface someInterface
{
   int someMethod(int x);
   string derivedType {get;}
}

public derivedClass : someInterface
{
   public int someMethod (int x) {...};
   public string derivedType
   {
      get {return "derivedType";}
   }
}
```

That is, make the property read-only, and implement it to return the hard-coded string.  Refactor as necessary.